# How to send a webhook request url for evernote on each create and update note event

Tags: php, evernote

I just tried to request a web hook url with end point http://xyz.php to be registered in evernote with a sandbox environment. I want to get notifications everytime when any user update or create any note in notebook. Am I following the right procedure to send the url with this endpoint or should I add any filter with the url and send different url with user id and notify filter?
I am using php for calling api.

My question is what should be the exact webhook url to be send? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The URL should be anything that can accept HTTP GET from Evernote servers. The possible formats are listed here: http://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/polling_notification.php#webhooks